# Monogame multiple objects same animation

Tags: c#, animation, sprite, monogame

as the titel say's I'm trying to make a game in Monogame, a Bomberman clone, but atm when I try to spawn more then one bomb the animation just moves to the new location. The game object stays where it is supposed to, but it does not have the animation. I think the problem is that it loads the same animation which has been loaded but I just cant seem to figure out how to get it to spawn a new animation everytime a bomb spawns.
I use Content.Load to get the sorite animation, and spawn the bomb with a clone() function with the animation.

```
var bombAni = new Dictionary<string, Animation>() {
            {"Bomb", new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Obstacle/Bomb"), 3) },
        };

        _sprites = new List<Sprite>() {

            new Player(animations) {
                _bomb = new Bomb(bombAni),
                Position = new Vector2(32, 32),
                Input = new Input() {
                    Up = Keys.W,
                    Down = Keys.S,
                    Left = Keys.A,
                    Right = Keys.D,
                    Space = Keys.Space,
                }
            }

        };

public void Play(Animation animation) {
        if (animation == _animation) {
            return;
        }

        _animation = animation;

        _animation.CurFrame = 0;

        _timer = 0;
    }

private void AddBomb(List<Sprite> sprites) {

        var bomb = _bomb.Clone() as Bomb;
        switch (_direction) {
            case "Up":
                bomb.Position = _position + new Vector2(0, -32);
                break;
            case "Down":
                bomb.Position = _position + new Vector2(0, 32);
                break;
            case "Left":
                bomb.Position = _position + new Vector2(-32, 0);
                break;
            case "Right":
                bomb.Position = _position + new Vector2(32, 0);
                break;
        }
        bomb.lifeSpan = 3f;
        bomb.Parent = this;
        bombCount++;

        sprites.Add(bomb);
    }

public Sprite(Dictionary<string, Animation> animations) {

        _animations = animations;
        _animationManager = new AnimationManager(_animations.First().Value);

    }


namespace CompetenceWeek.scripts {
public class Bomb : Sprite {

    public float lifeSpan;
    private float _timer;

    public Bomb(Dictionary<string, Animation> animations) : base(animations) {

    }

    public Bomb(Texture2D texture) : base(texture) {

    }


    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, List<Sprite> sprites) {
        _timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        SetAnimations();

        _animationManager.Update(gameTime);

        if (_timer > lifeSpan) {
            isDead = true;
        }

    }

}
```

}

```
namespace CompetenceWeek.scripts {
public class Sprite : ICloneable {

    protected AnimationManager _animationManager;

    protected Dictionary<string, Animation> _animations;

    protected Vector2 _position;

    protected Texture2D _texture;

    public bool Walkable { get; set; } = false;

    public bool isDead = false;


    public Player Parent { get; set; }

    public Input Input;

    public Vector2 Position {
        get { return _position; }
        set {
            _position = value;

            if(_animationManager != null) {
                _animationManager.Posistion = _position;
            }
        }
    }

    public float Speed = 2.5f;

    public Vector2 Velocity;

    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {

        if(_texture != null) {
            spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, Position, Color.White);
        } else if (_animationManager != null) {
            _animationManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("somthings not right");
        }


    }



    public Sprite(Dictionary<string, Animation> animations) {

        _animations = animations;
        _animationManager = new AnimationManager(_animations.First().Value);

    }

    public Sprite(Texture2D texture) {
        _texture = texture;
    }

    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime, List<Sprite> sprites) {
        SetAnimations();

        _animationManager.Update(gameTime);

        Position += Velocity;
        Velocity = Vector2.Zero;


    }

    protected virtual void SetAnimations() {
        if (Velocity.X > 0) {
            _animationManager.Play(_animations["PlayerRight"]);
        } else if (Velocity.X < 0) {
            _animationManager.Play(_animations["PlayerLeft"]);
        } else if (Velocity.Y > 0) {
            _animationManager.Play(_animations["PlayerDown"]);
        } else if (Velocity.Y < 0) {
            _animationManager.Play(_animations["PlayerUp"]);
        }
    }

    public object Clone() {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the relevant code with us?

Comment: It is there now, sorry first post here ^^;

Comment: Can you show the code for your Bomb class? It appears that when you are Cloning bomb, you are referencing the same instance of the animation as the existing Bomb. This is one of the problems with Shallow cloning.

Comment: Just added the Bomb class, but the clone is from the Sprite class but as far as I know this shouldt make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this segment:

```
protected Dictionary<string, Animation> _animations;

public object Clone() {
    return this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

When you perform a memberwise clone, it creates a shallow copy, reusing existing references to reference-type objects. This means that the Clone will share the same animation state with the original object.

The solution to this, is to instantiate a new copy of all of the Animations every time you want to clone Bomb.

Something like this:

```
public object Clone() {
    var bomb = (Bomb)this.MemberwiseClone();
    bomb.InitAnimations(new Dictionary<string, Animation>() {
        {"Bomb", new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Obstacle/Bomb"), 3) },
    };
    return bomb;
}
```

Comment: Yea this is what I've though too But i cant seem to access Content.Load from anyother place then in the game.cs class

Comment: In developing with MonoGame extensively, we've found that it is very useful to make the instance of Game available to other parts of the application. There are many ways to do this. The naive implementation is just make it available in the global space: https://github.com/EnigmaDragons/Astrocell/blob/master/MonoDragons.Core/Engine/GameInstance.cs You can have your Game instance call initialize on startup.

Comment: Okay it took me some time to figure out what you ment with the gameinstance but I got it to work by doing this
public override object Clone() {
            var bomb = new Bomb(new Dictionary<string, Animation>() {
                {"Bomb", new Animation(GameInstance.TheGame.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Obstacle/Bomb"), 3) },
            });
            return bomb;
        }
Thanks alot for your help! ^^